# Solving a 2nd order ODE with trigonometric coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How would one solve the following eigenvalue problem?

$y'' + (\cot(x) - \tan(x)) y' = \lambda y$

for $\lambda$ an arbitrary constant, $x \in [0, \pi/2]$, and boundary conditions

$y(0) = y(\pi/2) = 0$

Comment: PS posting complete solutions are more than welcomed, but I'll take any help

Answer (score 2):

The change of variables $t=\cos^2 x$ transforms this ODE into a particular case of the [Gauss hypergeometric equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricDifferentialEquation.html)
$$t(1-t)y''+(1-2t)y'-\frac{\lambda}{4}y=0,\tag{1}$$
The corresponding triple of parameters $(a,b,c)$ is given by 
$$a=\frac{1+\sqrt{1-\lambda}}{2}, \qquad b=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-\lambda}}{2}, \qquad c=1.$$

Independently of this, the equation (1) has two linearly independent solutions, one of which behaves as $1$ and another one as $\ln t$ as $t\rightarrow0$ (i.e. $x\rightarrow\frac{\pi}{2}$). It is impossible to construct out of this pair a linear combination vanishing as $t\rightarrow0$. Therefore the boundary problem does not admit nontrivial solutions.